# Never ending query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012, Amazon RDS

This is my simple query

```
update [dbo].[DeliveryPlan] 
set [Amount] = dp.Amount + 
                  case when @useAmountColumn = 1 and dbo.ConvertToInt(bs.Amount) > 0 
                         then dbo.ConvertToInt(bs.Amount) 
                         else @amount 
                  end
from
    BaseSpecification bs
join 
    BaseSpecificationStatusType t on (StatusTypeID = t.StatusTypeID)
join 
    [DeliveryPlan] dp on (dp.BaseSpecificationID = bs.BaseSpecificationID and dp.ItemID = @itemID)
where 
     bs.BaseID = 130 and t.IsActive = 1
```

It can't be finished. If where condition bs.BaseID=130 (update 7000 rows) change for bs.BaseID=3 (update 1000000 rows) it lasts 13 sec.

Statistics are actual, I think

In performance monitor I see 5% processor usage

When I use sp to watch active connections and for this query
tempdb_allocations is 32, tembdb_current - 32, reads - 32 000 000, cpu - 860 000 (query lasts 20 minutes)

What is the problem?

**UPDATE:** I added non-clustered index for `[DeliveryPlan]` - by `BaseSpecificationID + ItemID` and problem is gone. Unfortunately I see this problem every day with different queries. And problem disappears unpredicatedly.

Comment: Have you tried to move `dp.ItemID=@itemID` to the WHERE clause? I'm 90% sure it won't help, but I'm very interested about the result.

Comment: what about the indexes on joined columns? and on filtered columns? any hint from the query plan? what's the rowcount of table `BaseSpecificationStatusType`?

Comment: Another thing - I hope you understand the database page/row locking process. I assume noone is using the database except you... or?

Comment: noone is using. BaseSpecificationStatusType - 4 or 5 rows

Comment: i can see plan only for query with another where condition

Comment: BaseSpecificationStatusType .StatusTypeID, BaseSpecification.BaseSpecificationID,  - key columns

Answer (score 0):

You may suffer from a locking condition for your base tables.

Optimize your query to update `dp` directly to avoid update all rows of `DeliveryPlan`

```
update dp set [Amount] = dp.Amount + 
    case 
        when @useAmountColumn=1 and dbo.ConvertToInt(bs.Amount)>0 then 
            dbo.ConvertToInt(bs.Amount) 
        else @amount 
    end
from 
    BaseSpecification bs 
    join BaseSpecificationStatusType t on (bs.StatusTypeID = t.StatusTypeID) 
    join [DeliveryPlan] dp on (dp.BaseSpecificationID = bs.BaseSpecificationID)
where 
    bs.BaseID = 130 
    and t.IsActive = 1
    and dp.ItemID = @itemID
```

Comment: i'm missing the point: the proposed solution is the very same query with a filter moved from `join` to `where` clause. a change already tested that produced no effect.

Comment: @Paolo Note the statement after the `UPDATE`, original query is another `DeliveryPlan` table instead of using the `dp`. So the update *is* updating all of the rows instead of the target `ItemID`.

Comment: @Paolo Opps I see now, I thought it is not OK not using alias but table name in UPDATE, but I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will perform better and in a different way as the join conditions will narrow down the number of rows in the first go itself, rather than waiting for the where clause to execute. The execution plan will be different for both (with where/ without where).

```
UPDATE dp
  SET Amount = dp.Amount + CASE
                       WHEN @useAmountColumn = 1
                        AND dbo.ConvertToInt( bs.Amount ) > 0 THEN dbo.ConvertToInt( bs.Amount )
                           ELSE @amount
                       END
  FROM BaseSpecification bs
   JOIN BaseSpecificationStatusType t ON
                                        ( bs.StatusTypeID = t.StatusTypeID
                                      AND bs.BaseID = 130
                                      AND t.IsActive = 1
                                        )
   JOIN DeliveryPlan dp ON
                          ( dp.BaseSpecificationID = bs.BaseSpecificationID
                        AND dp.ItemID = @itemID
                          );
```

Comment: your comment is not a comment: should go inside the answer. also why you guess that join would work faster? are you sure that the query optimizer will not choose to handle them the same way?

Comment: again, this is not a comment: all the details about your answer (why you propose it, tech details and so on) have to go in the answer, where they can be read all at once without hunting in the comment list. please complete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem mentioned in the update part is that it comes and goes randomly, it sounds like bad parameter sniffing. When the problem happens you could look into plan cache to check if the query plan looks ok and in case it doesn't, what are the values the plan was created with (you can find them in the leftmost object in the plan) and for example use sp_recompile and see what kind of plan you'll get the next time.

Comment: I tried to redefine parameters in the sp to change this bad parameter sniffing which is the result of outdate statistics as I know. And statistics were good.

Comment: @MihailKatrikh Parameter sniffing can happen even if statistics are 100% accurate, and your data can be such that certain IDs would need a different kind of plan than others. Looking at the plans when the performance is bad should give you some kind of idea what happens